# How to get selected row data from <DataGrid/>?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a [Material-UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/) table component with many rows:

```
<DataGrid
        className="dataGrid"
        rows={data}
        columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)}
        pageSize={9}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
        checkboxSelection
      />
```

This table returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "code": "code0",
    "article": "article0",
    "price": 100,
    "vat": null,
    "status": null,
    "company_id": 12
  },
  {
    {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "code1",
    "article": "article1",
    "price": 100,
    "vat": null,
    "status": null,
    "company_id": 12
  }
]
```

Is there a way to extract specific row using `id`?(exemple id=1, it should return the whole second row).

Comment: Are you trying to get the object out of the array? Or request it from the `<DataGrid>`? To get it out of the array a standard `.find()` should do the trick.

Comment: @DBS i'm trying to select a single row from <DataGrid>.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't access the data directly?

Comment: i'm building a dashboard, where there's update button at the end of each row, clicking on update button should send the row data to where i can modify this row data.
Back to your question, becase data is coming directly from API. i can't abuse requesting this data directly meanwhile the data is already rendred once.

Comment: I'm reading this single row selection (https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/selection/#single-row-selection), but i'm not sure if this helps or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract id and use it, use `response.data.find((x) => x.id === props.data)`

example:

```
const loadArticleDetails = async () => {
    const response = await getUsers(id)
    setArticleData(response.data.find((x) => x.id === props.data))
}
```